# How to check if a line exists in a file using batch command?

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file where it has some text in it. I would like to check if "The system cannot find the file specified" is present in the text file using batch commands.

I have tried in my local machine using FINDSTR command and it works as expected. But when I tried it in remote machine it always shows match even if the string is not existing in the text file.

Below is my code:

```
--> Getting the latest folder in a directory.

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o "\\BuildServer\xyz_build\Daily Build (Main)\"') DO (
    SET a=%%i
)

findstr /c:"The system cannot find the file specified" "F:\Deploy\FreshBuild\%a%.txt" (where %a% is the file name)
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
    ECHO String exists.
)
```

FYI: I have checked the file path by echo'ing the "F:\Deploy\FreshBuild\%a%.txt" path.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using batch and not PowerShell?

Comment: I am not much familiar with PowerShell, and using batch file I have scheduled a task.

Answer (score 0):

First, it sounds like you are checking if a file exists. You can just use:

```
if exist {insert file name here} (
    rem file exists
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
)
```

Next, what is the output if you change that `SET a=%%i` to an `ECHO a=%%i`. (are your folders showing up?)

After that, your findstr is happening outside of the loop. so it would only check the last value of a, right? That doesn't seem like your intention.

Comment: Nope, I am checking whether "The system cannot find the file specified" string is present in "F:\Deploy\FreshBuild\%a%.txt" file. Actually there is some piece of code after FOR loop. Which will create a text file with the %a% name (latest folder name) and has logs in it (I have used a robocopy command for copying a server build to a local folder) as 'robocopy source desti >> %a%.txt'. I tried printing the path as 'ECHO "F:\Deploy\FreshBuild\%a%.txt"' It prints, "F:\Deploy\FreshBuild\Daily Build (Main)_20130205.1.txt". But when I tried to print the text file, I am getting EHCO is OFF message.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misread your original post a bit. I will update my answer shortly (possibly delete).

Comment: I tried getting text as 'set /p text=<"F:\Deploy\FreshBuild\%a%.txt"', and tried printing ECHO %text% even this shows ECHO is OFF.

Comment: so if you do set text="F:\Deploy\FreshBuild\%a%.txt", what does echo %text% show?

Comment: When I tried set text="F:\Deploy\FreshBuild\%a%.txt", the output is ECHO if OFF.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense, man. If you do set text="C:\bah\blah\%jksdljkdfjksldf%.txt"
echo %text% it will output, "C:\bah\blah\.txt" . You must be typing something wrong... or I am going crazy. Also, check my update to my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23998/discussion-between-sham-and-gray)